# Windows Workflow: How to specify namespace URI for OperationName parameter in Send activity?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

When I use **Send** activity from the toolbox in the designer to communicate with a SOAP web service, the activity sends the correct SOAP request, except that the namespace in "operation" XML element is always the default http://tempuri.org.

```
<s:Body><HelloWorld xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">...
```

How to change that to point to my URI http://myuri.com?

The *OperationName* property in the activity cannot be specified like a full URI, so it's just the name of the operation "HelloWorld".

I have the full URI specified in "Action" property (*SOAPAction* in the HTTP header) and it looks like this: http://myuri.com/HelloWorld.

I'm using the latest version of WF which is 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace should be specified in the parameter *ServiceContractName* as:

> {http://myuri.com/}WebServiceSoap

where *WebServiceSoap* is the name of the contract specified in the configuration file.